# Random values in array with Timber (Twig) and Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, twig, timber

I merged values of two arrays in a new array.

But I would like to take random values from this array and put them in a loop. That those values iterate in this loop.

```
{% set myArray = [] %}
{% set list1 = options.transitions_repeater %}
{% set list2 = options.transitions_wahou_repeater %}

{% set myArray = list1|merge(list2) %}

{% for key, val in myArray %}
    {{ val|join(', ') }}
{% endfor %}

{% for item in options.projets %}
<li data-transisition="{{ myArray }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

I got the message :  **Array to string conversion in XX on line XX**

[image: Array]

**Output :**
animBottom
animTop
animLeft
directionRight
circles
cube

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your merged list is still a multidimensional array.You could solve your issue with the following code, however it's preferable to move the logic of creating the (single dimensional) array to your controller (*then you could remove the filter `first` in the snippet*)

```
{% for item in options.projets %}
<li data-transisition="{{ myArray[random(myArray| keys)] | first }}"></li>
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/agah1m)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That work great ! One to transform the logic to single dimensional ?